# Joomla: Need accordion to be set as expanded

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I need the accordion "Contact Form" in Joomla to be set as expanded by default. To do this I m trying to override files `../components/com_contact/tmpl/default.php and default_form.php` but I dont find what needs to be change to do this.

Seeing the code in the Chrome developer Tools I think I find that this line

```
<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="display-form">
```

shoul be set to:

```
<div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="display-form">
```

But I dont find where in the phps file is this generate?

PD: I think the line is generate here, but still dont know what needs to be change:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('presentation_style') == 'sliders') : ?>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addSlide', 'slide-contact', JText::_('COM_CONTACT_EMAIL_FORM'), 'display-form'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this snippet after JText or the 'display-form'.

```
array('class'=>'in')
```

If it doesn't work then check out the documentation online and you should be able to find your solution.

http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlBootstrap.html

Comment: I tried to add it. But still dont expand it. What I finally did was not a proper solution, I delete all the line inside the if sentence, so the form was displayed from the beggining

Comment: Were you able to make use of the documentation?